# Quantum Double Slit Experiment and Schrodinger's Equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, double-slit-experiment

Consider the quantum double slit experiment, where a plane wave, with frequency $\omega$, travels in a direction orthogonal to the slit screen and is incident on that screen. Then, from slit 1, a radial wave emerges of the form $r^{-1}_1 e^{-i(kr_1- \omega t)}$, where $r_1$ is measured from slit 1, and, from slit 2, a radial wave emerges of the form $r^{-1}_2 e^{-i(kr_2-\omega t)}$, where $r_2$ is measured from the slit 2. Note, $r^{-1}_1 e^{-i(kr_1-\omega t)}$ satisfies Schrodinger’s equation when expressed in polar coordinates $(r_1, \theta_1)$ and is an eigenfunction of the Hamiltonian of that equation. Similarly, $r^{-1}_2 e^{-i(kr_2-\omega t)}$ satisfies Schrodinger’s equation when expressed in polar coordinates $(r_2, \theta_2)$ and is an eigenfunction of the Hamiltonian of that equation.

The total wave function is the sum of the two waves: $(r^{-1}_1 e^{-ikr_1} + r^{-1}_2 e^{-ikr_2})e^{i \omega t}$. This produces the famous interference pattern at the detector.

If both radial waves are represented in terms of the same polar coordinate system $(r, \theta)$, instead of in terms of $(r_1, \theta_1)$ and $(r_2, \theta_2)$, as above, then will the total wave function satisfy Schrodinger’s equation, in the $(r,\theta)$ coordinate system? Clearly, we need to have the total wave function be an eigenfunction of the Hamiltonian in that equation.

So I am doubting that the sum of the above two radial waves is a solution to Schrodinger’s equation. However, it must be, since we know that the experiment involves interference between the two radial waves of the wave function. So, how do we show that the sum of the above two radial waves is a solution to Schrodinger's equation?

Perhaps, to gain some insight, another way to think about this is consider two radial waves that have the same $\omega$, $k$, phase, and center point. Assume both are represented in the same polar coordinate system $(r, \theta)$ where the origin of coordinates is at the waves’ center point. We then move each wave  so that they have different center points, such that neither is at the origin of coordinates.  However, I do not think that the cartesian translation operators, which one might use to do this, when represented in $(r, \theta)$ polar coordinates, commutes with the Hamiltonian in $(r, \theta)$ polar form.

Answer (score 0):

If both wave function are solutions of the wave equation then their sum also is. This is true for solutions of any linear wave equation, such as the one involved in the Maxwell equations, as well as the Schrödinger, Dirac and Klein-Gordon equations.

However the solutions proposed require a source in their origin. A solution for a source at one point does not satisfy the equation with a source at a different point.

Specifically, the single slit solution is not a solution of the dual slit problem.

Comment: I think the radial wave function, as I described it, has to be centered at the origin of coordinates in order to be a solution of the wave equation, is what I seem to find.

Comment: @user3536736 You'd need to express both the wavefuctions in the same polar coordinates and write the SE also in the same coordinates to be able to see that the superposition satisfies the SE. Currently, you're writing the superposition in two different coordinates.

Comment: However, as @my2cts points out, you should be confident that this would happen simply based on the linearity of the SE.

Comment: @DvijD.C. The third paragraph of the question talks about doing just that. We know that radial wave function (1/r)exp(-i(kr-wt)) satisfies the polar form of the free-particle SE when the coordinate origin is at the wave’s center. If I then transform that radial wave function so that its center is no longer at the origin of coordinates, the transformed wave function no longer satisfies the same SE. When there are two slits, at least one radial wave must have its center not be at the origin of coordinates. Hence, it will not satisfy the polar form of the free particle SE.

Comment: So, how would one mathematically represent the two radial waves,  where one has center at slit 1 and the other has center at slit 2, so that they satisfy the free particle SE in the space between the slits and the detector?

Comment: @my2cts "This is true for the solutions of any linear wave equation" This is a common misconception. Only differential equations which are both linear and also homogeneous satisfy the property that linear combinations of solutions also solve the equation. Of course the Schrödinger equation is both linear and homogeneous.

Comment: My edit link to the original question is gone. Why is that?